# Youtube API v3 Information about access_token

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I have some questions about the access_token usage on server-side web apps.

1. How should I keep the access_token valid?
   Is it possible to check it before making a request, or should I just try to make a request and renew it if error? Or maybe set up a cronjob that renews all the access_tokens?
2. The expires_in field, is it seconds? Can an access_token expire before this value?

Comment: Save the refresh token someplace.  after an hour the access token will expire.  use the refresh token to get a new one.  Technically speaking you can just use the refresh token to get an access token every time your script runs.

Answer (score 0):

**How should I keep the access_token valid?** 
You can't. It will expire as sure as eggs is eggs. All you can do is get a replacement.

**Is it possible to check it before making a request, or should I just try to make a request and renew it if error?**

You can check it by referring to the expiration time(1), or try and catch the 401 exception(2).

**Or maybe set up a cronjob that renews all the access_tokens?**

Yep (3)

Congratulations, you've won a prize by enumerating all three access token refresh policies :-). As to which one should you use, it depends. You need to decide if speed, user experience, or network bandwidth matter most to you. By far the safest is to catch the 401, and refresh, because that deals with all eventualities. With that in place, you may decide to speed things up by doing a refresh after 3550 seconds.

**The expires_in field, is it seconds?**

Yes

**Can an access_token expire before this value?**

Good question. I'm going to say yes, if the user withdraws permission to the app. Otherwise no.